# How to sort rows in "SELECT ... FOR ALL ENTRIES ...", ORDER BY is not accepted

Tags: sorting, select, abap, opensql

I am selecting a table that has multiple of the same records (same `REQUEST_ID`) with different `VERSION_NO`.  So I want to sort it descending so I can take the highest number (latest record).

This is what I have...

```
IF it_temp2[] IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT request_id
         version_no
         status
         item_list_id
         mod_timestamp
  FROM ptreq_header INTO TABLE it_abs3
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_temp2
  WHERE item_list_id EQ it_temp2-itemid.
ENDIF.
```

So version_no is one of the SELECT field but I want to sort that field (descending) and only take the first row.

I was doing some research and read that SORT * BY * won't work with FOR ALL ENTRIES.  But that's just my understanding from reading up.
Please let me know how I can make this work.  Thanks

Comment: This is a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group], with [many existing solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply sort the itab after the select and delete all adjecent duplicates afterwards, if wanted:

```
SORT it_abs3 BY request_id [ASCENDING] version_no DESCENDING.
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM it_abs3 COMPARE request_id.
```

Depending on the amount of expected garbage (to be deleted lines) in the itab an SQL approach is better.  See Used_By_Already's answer.

Comment: best and simplest answer for my situation. I sort request_id ascending and version_no descending inside my read table loop and it solved the prob.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the term "latest" to indicate "the most recent entry", then the field `mod_timestamp` appears to be relevant and you could use it this way to choose only the most recent records for each request_id.

```
SELECT
      request_id
    , version_no
    , status
    , item_list_id
    , mod_timestamp
FROM ptreq_header h
      INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        request_id
                      , MAX(mod_timestamp) AS latest
                  FROM ptreq_header
                  GROUP BY 
                        request_id
            ) l
                  ON h.request_id = l.request_id
                        AND h.mod_timestamp = l.latest
```

If you want the largest version_no, then instead of `MAX(mod_timestamp)` use `MAX(version_no)`

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the `it_abs3` as a sorted table with key that would consist of the columns you want to sort by.

You can also sort the table after the query.

```
SORT it_abs3 BY ...
```